# AWS CLI Query to find Shared Security Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I am trying to write a query to return results of any referenced security group not owned by the current account.

This means I am trying to show security groups that are being used as part of a peering connection from another VPC.

There are a couple of restrictions.

Show the entire security group details (security group id, description)
Only show security groups where IpPermissions.UserIdGroupPairs has a Value and where that value is not equal to the owner of the security group

I am trying to write this using a single AWS CLI cmd vs a bash script or python script.

Any thoughts?

Heres what I have so far.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --query "SecurityGroups[?IpPermissions.UserIdGroupPairs[*].UserId != '`aws sts get-caller-identity --query 'Account' --output text`']"
```

Comment: I would recommend doing this in a programming language (eg Python) rather than using the AWS CLI. It would involve making a list of all security groups in your account. Then, traverse those security groups and check whether a referenced security group is in that list of security groups. This is much easier in a program rather than trying to do it from shell.

Answer (score 0):

Following is Python 3.8 based AWS Lambda, but you can change a bit to use as python script file to execute on any supported host machine.

```
import boto3
import ast


config_service = boto3.client('config')

# Refactor to extract out duplicate code as a seperate def
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    results = get_resource_details()
    for resource in results:
        if "configuration" in resource:
            config=ast.literal_eval(resource)["configuration"]
            if "ipPermissionsEgress" in config:
                ipPermissionsEgress=config["ipPermissionsEgress"]
                for data in ipPermissionsEgress:
                    for userIdGroupPair in data["userIdGroupPairs"]:
                        if userIdGroupPair["userId"] != "123456789111":
                            print(userIdGroupPair["groupId"])
            elif "ipPermissions" in config: 
                ipPermissions=config["ipPermissions"]
                for data in ipPermissions:
                    for userIdGroupPair in data["userIdGroupPairs"]:
                        if userIdGroupPair["userId"] != "123456789111":
                            print(userIdGroupPair["groupId"])


def get_resource_details():
    query = "SELECT configuration.ipPermissions.userIdGroupPairs.groupId,configuration.ipPermissionsEgress.userIdGroupPairs.groupId,configuration.ipPermissionsEgress.userIdGroupPairs.userId,configuration.ipPermissions.userIdGroupPairs.userId WHERE resourceType = 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup' AND configuration <> 'null'"
    results = config_service.select_resource_config(
        Expression=query,
        Limit=100
    ) # you might need to refacor to add support huge list of records using NextToken
    return results["Results"]
```